# Smooth SVG Axis Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I'm attempting to render a scrolling axis at 60 fps.  It was nearly as simple as updating the scale's domain and calling `axisGroupElement.call(axis)` inside a loop.  Unfortunately at different scales that produces some very smooth animations where the ticks and the text will jiggle.

**http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/fTcrU/11/**

- The jiggling probably depends on the width of the container and the length of the scale's domain... try changing the drop down for different results.

So, I thought I'd be creative and render the axis 3 times the size I needed and transform the entire group for a smoother scroll.  That unfortunately produces nearly the same results.

I went a step further and moved the entire SVG element, which is a little smoother, but a huge hack.

There's also a problem where I can't get my own transform scrolling at the same rate the redraw scrolls at.  It seems to fall behind over time.  I thought I had it nailed down by calculating milliseconds per pixel, but that doesn't appear to be totally correct.  It's interesting to see how it certain resolutions it'll tick along at 1px, store the remaining milliseconds, and then some ticks will adjust it 2px.

Is there anything I can do or is scrolling these irregular widths/time spans always going to produce animations that aren't smooth?

TIA!

Comment: i don't know if this could help but for me for example (safari latest version, retina mb on macos mountain lion) redraw is the smoothest of the 3, even changing the time on the menu

Comment: Yea, it seems to be the worst on Chrome.  Simply redrawing in IE is really smooth on IE of all browsers.

Comment: I appreciate your desire to get it to be perfect and the thoroughness with which you're exploring this issue. I wish I had a good answer. FWIW, on my Mac Chrome Redraw+Transform looks good. As an aside, [here's what](http://jsfiddle.net/fTcrU/12/) adding a CSS style property `shape-rendering: crispEdges` to `.tick line` does. Doesn't fix it, just a different result. Finally, note that mbostock released [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) and wasn't bothered by the axis rendering in his example :) Also, view source to see what moves that timeline. Slightly different than yours.

Comment: @Langdon Did you happen to solve this problem?

Comment: @VividD Sadly, no.  It still looks really bad under certain circumstances.. in all browsers, really.

Answer (score 0):

The axis redraw example looks nicer because it sets the transform values more exactly as floating point numbers, whereas your calculation for transform produces integers.

I've amended your algorithm to produce floats, and now the "Redraw" and "Redraw and Transform" examples look identical.

http://jsfiddle.net/xJJHM/1/

The relevant change is

```
_left -= msPassed / _msPerPixel;
```

I tried to do the same with the left-positioning, but it turns out that you need integer values for that.

I found an article/video by Paul Irish which explains this in more detail: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/